# jQuery Date Range Picker set closest month when move to next month

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface

I have used Date range picker by http://jszen.com
I always need to show closest month side by side. When moving next month or previous months as well.
As I change the month of one section, other month should follow to the previous month accordingly.

Example: When I move to August month from month 2, the month 1 should move to July accordingly. I can't find any configuration from their Demonstrations.

Please visit: https://rawgit.com/longbill/jquery-date-range-picker/master/index.html

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: I think this is helpful http://2008.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePickerMultiMonth.html

Comment: Thank you very much. But I have no idea how do I use this code with jQuery Date Range Picker that I already used. This is a different date picker is it.

Answer (score 0):

Found it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dateRangePicker').dateRangePicker({
       stickyMonths: true,
    });
});
```